# how do i decrease the number of lines i have?

Tags: python, loops

the function of this program is to calculate the summation. it starts when the user enters  four integers separated by single spaces, P, Q, N, and M that represent the parameters in summation.So it calculates the value of Sn modulo M for given numbers P, Q, N, and M. the question here is how do i make it efficient with less lines.

```
P,Q,N,M=map(int,input().split())
sum1=0
for k in range(1,N+1,1):
   sum1+=pow(P,k)*pow(k,Q)
print(sum1%M)
```

Comment: the fastest way would be to use a mathematical formula to calculate this (if there is one)

Answer (score 1):

You can use generator comprehension:

```py
print(sum(pow(P, k) * pow(k, Q) for k in range(1, N + 1)) % M)
```

although it is not *more efficient*; it is just rewriting the code differently.

Comment: it shows a non zero exit code in the output, thank you though

Comment: @user9910282 well then you either have a different version or somehow copied the code wrongly, or the error is not related to this anyways because their code works completely fine for me and there is no visible issue with it